# why does this JQuery program not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, html

i made a simple html program (with JQuery) that makes it so that the page gets angrier and angrier every time. however, it seems to not work and i've checked every nook and cranny, searched through every line, with it still not working.

(forgive me for this bad explanation im still new to the site)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="button"> dont press the button </button>
        <button class="button" style="display:none;"> another button </button>
        <p id="warning"> </p>
        
        <script>
            var clickCount = 0;
            $(".button").click(function(){
                clickCount += 1;
                console.log(clickCount);
                if (clickCount.value == 1) {
                    $("#warning").text("I said DONT PRESS!");
                }
                else if (clickCount.value == 2) {
                    $("#warning").text("Come on!");
                }
                else if (clickCount.value == 3) {
                    $("#warning").text("Your really getting on my nerves right now.");
                }
                else if (clickCount.value == 4) {
                    $("#warning").text("Is this all you do?");
                }
                else if (clickCount.value == 5) {
                    $("#warning").text("ALRIGHT, PLAYTIMES OVER! NO MORE BUTTON!");
                    $("#button").css({"display":"none"});
                }
                else if (clickCount.value == 6) {
                    $("#warning").text("Sigh...");
                    $("#button").css({"display":"block"});
                }
                else if (clickCount.value == 7) {
                    $("#warning").text("Alright then... how about this for a challenge?");
                    $("#button").css({"display":"block"});
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

for some reason, when I click the button the text doesnt show up. anyways im in a hurry so i cant explain much.

Comment: Why are you using .value for clickCount. The if conditions should just be if (clickCount == 1) { }

Answer (score 0):

update: just realized I'm a huge idiot and i didn't need to put .value at all
thanks for helping

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using clickCount.value in your if statements? Shouldn't you just be checking clickCount.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.